# Setting up a developing environment with appfog

Tags: database, appfog

I am usually developing php applications locally and upload them to the server with ftp. 
I am examine appfog as an alternative I want though to set up the developing enviroment 
on localhost and use the same database with the staging and production. 
Is that possible or do I have to use another service to host my database and use the appfog for the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using a hosted database service for your app, then you can use the same database on both local and production servers. There are many binds available on AppFog.

But if you are going with SQLite, you should consider using a persistent database solution. It is not recommended on production environment in AppFog. Every time you update your app, your SQLite database will be blown away.

Since AppFog databases are not externally accessible, you'll have to tunnel into them. You will find more information here:

http://blog.appfog.com/how-to-manage-your-appfog-database-from-your-desktop-on-the-other-side-of-the-world/